# Deleting files using Delete button not working on Fedora

Tags: fedora

This is on a fedora machine (Fedora 20)

My problem when ever I simply pressing delete button (Del) after selecting a file/folder won't delete the selected file/folder. But the combination `shift + Del` works fine.

Please let me know how to activate the delete button for moving files/folders to Trash folder.

Also let me know if there is common option to activate the keys in Fedora.

Comment: Acutally it is a dupe. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111141/24509

Comment: Yes I agree. But  normal people like me search answers for by specifying their operating system name only ..right ?

Comment: Yes, of course. I only realize it just now after answering. No problem with asking.

Comment: Ok, sure. I will leave my answer as it is. The link above will serve its purpose to link to the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> delete files permanently. To move to trash, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> instead. To disable this safety feature in Gnome3, navigate to the hidden directory `/home/user/.config/nautilus` and edit the `accel` file by changing:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash" "<Primary>Delete")
```

to

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash" "Delete")
```

Then restart nautilus by logging out and logging back in.

Comment: Editing this file will allow me to put the files to into Trash without pressing the "Ctrl" button ?

Comment: Yes, it will allow the Delete to send files to trash with Ctrl key.